# Spark - GraphX: mapReduceTriplets vs aggregateMessages

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am running by a tutorial 
http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/big-data-mini-course/graph-analytics-with-graphx.html

And at some point we use the mapReduceTriplets operations. This returns the expected result

```
// Find the oldest follower for each user
val oldestFollower: VertexRDD[(String, Int)] = userGraph.mapReduceTriplets[(String, Int)](
  // For each edge send a message to the destination vertex with the attribute of the source vertex
  edge => Iterator((edge.dstId, (edge.srcAttr.name, edge.srcAttr.age))),
  // To combine messages take the message for the older follower
  (a, b) => if (a._2 > b._2) a else b
)
```

But the IntelliJ points me that mapReduceTriplets is deprecated (as of 1.2.0) and should be replaced by aggregateMessages

```
// Find the oldest follower for each user
val oldestFollower: VertexRDD[(String, Int)] = userGraph.aggregateMessages()[(String, Int)](
  // For each edge send a message to the destination vertex with the attribute of the source vertex
  edge => Iterator((edge.dstId, (edge.srcAttr.name, edge.srcAttr.age))),
  // To combine messages take the message for the older follower
  (a, b) => if (a._2 > b._2) a else b
)
```

So I run the exact same code but then I don't have any output. Is that the expected result or should I change something due to the cahnge of aggregateMessages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you need something like this:

```
val oldestFollower: VertexRDD[(String, Int)] = userGraph.aggregateMessages[(String, Int)]
(
    // For each edge send a message to the destination vertex with the attribute of the source vertex
    sendMsg = { triplet => triplet.sendToDst(triplet.srcAttr.name, triplet.srcAttr.age) },
   // To combine messages take the message for the older follower
    mergeMsg = {(a, b) => if (a._2 > b._2) a else b}
)
```

You can find `aggregateMessages` function signature and useful examples at [Grapx proggraming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#aggregate-messages-aggregatemessages) page. Hope this helps.